# Why is my font awesome not working in child theme but plugin?

Tags: css, fonts, font-awesome

I had tried to put

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">  or <link rel="stylesheet" href="mypathto/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

into my page template, what I had done wrong, I include the font-awesome.min.css in my child theme. I also tried to put the following code into my child theme function.php, help, appreciate.

```html
<?php
function buddyboss_child_scripts_font()
  {
    
    wp_enqueue_style( 'buddyboss-childss-custom', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/css/font-awesome.min.css' );
  
  }
  add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'buddyboss_child_scripts_font', 9999 );
 
?>
```

Comment: Try to remove the 9999 from the add_action and check if it works, if not, open the chrome console and check if the file is loaded or not and eventually that the path is right

Comment: it give an error in console. GET http://weby.com/wp-content/themes/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.3.0 404 (Not Found). I have paste that file already, still not working. And, in my plugin, I don't even need that file, why?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to add Fontawesome in WP, 
you must add these lines inside your functions.php file

```
// Load Font Awesome
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_font_awesome' );
function enqueue_font_awesome() {

    wp_enqueue_style( 'font-awesome', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' );

}
```